# Whitenoise and django-compressor cause 404 for compressed files

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-compressor

Trying to deploy a Django application to Heroku using **whitenoise** and **django-compressor**.

Deploying it to production with `DEBUG = False` and `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True`, all my static assets can be accessed without a problem. However, all the compressed files return a 404, e.g.:

> http://*.herokuapp.com/static/CACHE/css/fbfaa35dc638.css Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Either enabling `DEBUG` or disabling `COMPRESS_ENABLED` fixes the problem, but of course is not what I want.

I'm also setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`, but changing this doesn't help.

Some settings (note I have a settings directory with e.g. `base.py`, `local.py`, etc. that's why I need an extra `../` on the paths):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

In my base template:

```
{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
{% block css %}{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}

[...]

{% compress js %}
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
{% block js %}{% endblock js %}
{% endcompress %}
```

Again, moving them out of the compress blocks fixes the issue. Just the compressed files can't be found.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention one setting I added as per the [deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/#templates), namely this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['loaders'] = [
    (
        'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ]
    ),
]
```

Removing this setting makes the page work again. HOWEVER, the JS and CSS files are not compressed... What's going on?

**Edit 2**

This is not a duplicate of [Django staticfiles not found on Heroku (with whitenoise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507140/django-staticfiles-not-found-on-heroku-with-whitenoise) :

- The problem in my question arises from django-compressor, not whitenoise alone
- They're not getting 404s, but rather 500s.
- Their issue was that they forgot to run collectstatic... Which is not the case here.

Comment: I have the exact issue like you, but not on Heroku. I use django cookiecutter project, but the Issue is the same. Any file in the "CACHE" folder returns a 404. Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django staticfiles not found on Heroku (with whitenoise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507140/django-staticfiles-not-found-on-heroku-with-whitenoise)

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a known problem.

According to Squebe - "Compressor's Online mode doesn't work on Heroku because Whitenoise only checks the static folder when the app is loaded (see my comment on issue #680). To use compressor in production I think you need to use it in Offline mode and run python manage.py compress before the app loads using Heroku's post compile hook."

[No way to get this to work on Heroku #486](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/486)

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. In the meantime, I switched to django-pipeline and it works out of the box!

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan. That worked for me. Just in case anybody else needs it: just add the contents of [this file](https://github.com/nigma/heroku-django-cookbook/blob/master/bin/run_compress) to `bin/post_compile` at your repo — at least that made the trick for me. Also, as I use `.buildpacks` and as I need `bower_components` to exist before the _compression_, I inverted the order, letting NodeJS in line 1 and Python in line 2 at `.buildpacks`.