# Django staticfiles not found on Heroku (with whitenoise)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

This question seems to be asked several time but I can not fix it.

I deployed a django app on production with `DEBUG = False`. I set my `allowed_host`. 
I used `{% load static from staticfiles %}` to load static files. I exactly write the settings sugested by Heroku doc :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

BUT I got an error 500. And got this traceback (by mail)

```
...
`cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name (clean_name, self))
...
ValueError: The file ‘app/css/font.css’ could not be found with <whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7febf600a7f0>.`
```

When I run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` 
All seems ok :

`276 static files copied to '/app/annuaire/staticfiles', 276 post-processed.`

Does anyone have an idea to help me, please ?

Thanks

EDIT :

```
annuaire
|-- /annuaire
|-- -- /settings.py
|-- /app
|-- -- /static/...`
```

wsgi.py

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise


application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: Django only usually calls that particular function when DEBUG=False so I'm puzzled that you could get that error with DEBUG=True. I'd suggest testing your app locally with DEBUG=False, running `collectstatic` and then `runserver` and see if you get that error. Could it be that you  just haven't committed that particular file?

Comment: Sorry! When Debug is False, you are right!

Comment: Have you printed `STATIC_ROOT` to ensure it is the same as '`/app/annuaire/staticfiles'`?

Comment: I just did it (locally) I got `In [3]: settings.STATIC_ROOT
Out[3]: '/Users/vincentpoulain/xxxx/annuaire/annuaire/staticfiles'` :/

Comment: I tried to change to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../app/staticfiles')`

Comment: It does not works... & now when I run collectstatic on heroku I got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/annuaire/static'`

Comment: Out of curiosity, try a different storage backend. `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

Comment: Already tried. Does not work :/

Comment: After `collectstatic` I don't have any staticfiles folder in heroku...

Comment: You need to get things working locally with DEBUG=False before you try pushing to Heroku as that only complicates things. I don't think this is a settings problem as your original settings looked fine. I think it's probably that the `app/css/font.css` file is missing or in the wrong place.

Comment: My `/` page does not work whule `/admin` is well rendered. Moreover, I check and my static files can be returned by the web server: `http://localhost:8000/static/app/style.css` returns a HTTP 200. In my console displays `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27`

Comment: Okay, now it works locally but still does not work on heroku. I have nothing to debug, crazy

Comment: I just added an answer that works for Django 2>= and whitenoise 4>=

Answer (score 10):

With `DEBUG=False`, what originals use to work does not work for me anymore.

However a fix by enabling `whitenoise` on `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py` solved it. Best to be just below `SecurityMiddleware`.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # add this line
    #Other middleware...
]
```

```

According to the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/whitenoise/stable/whitenoise.pdf), it actually needs to be enabled in the first place.

Comment: This worked for me. In heroku's launch django instructions they say to include it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets, but I started with their heroku-django-template https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template and it was not included in that

Answer (score 7):

I got it. I needed to add

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput;
```

in my Procfile. Heroku doc said that `collecticstatic` is automatically triggered.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Thanks

Comment: or just remove the environmental variable `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` from your app settings through the [dashboard](https://id.heroku.com/login). What it's important is this: Do NOT turn its value to 0, just delete this env variable completely. In that way you should not have to edit your `Procfile`. Then, all should work (at least they worked for me!).

Credits go to: [YunoJuno](http://tech.yunojuno.com/django-whitenoise-and-heroku-s-ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: @YunoJuno thanks man... Hours spent trying to debug this s*** and you just saved me!

Answer (score 5):

For me following worked.

## settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') #this is not used
# Add static folder to STATIC_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> Note
>
> This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given
>   prefix is local (e.g. /static/) and not a URL (e.g.
>   http://static.example.com/).
>
> Also this helper function only serves the actual STATIC_ROOT folder;
>   it doesn’t perform static files discovery like
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the Python application in Heroku uses the built-in web server and does not serve static files.

You can use the app of the [whitenoise](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets), this working solution is 100%.

Suppose you have already generated static files, for example:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Next you need to do this:

1) `$ pip install whitenoise`

2) add string "whitenoise==3.3.0" in your **requirements.txt**

3) add code in **settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

4) add this code in **app/wsgi.py**

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: modification of `wsgi.py` is not needed anymore

Answer (score 2):

for BASE_DIR you need to a double dirname if your settings are not in the root but in /projectname/ folder :

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# for /static/root/favicon.ico    
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles', 'root')
```

template.html

```
{%  load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static "app/css/font.css" %}">
```

app tree for this example:

```
annuaire
|-- /annuaire
|-- -- /settings.py
|-- /app
|-- /static/app/css/font.css
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it but it still does not work... I edited my django app tree in main question post.

Comment: It so weird when I collectstatic I got `275 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 1 unmodified, 276 post-processed.` but on heroku bash: staticfiles is still empty ...

Comment: @vpoulain That's because each new Heroku process runs in its own ephemeral filesystem, so the new files won't be seen by any other process. (See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). `collectstatic` must be run during the initial push for the files to be persisted.

Comment: @vpoulain check the app tree, for your code i think you need to use STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'app','static'),
) or move static folder to the root

Comment: @Meska this is bit confusing, where to write `staticfiles` and where to write `static`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above answers, it can also be that you have not specified a correct **STATIC_ROOT** as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#deployment

For me, the solution was adding this to the end of my production settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/app/static/"
```

To know where your static folder is in your heroku run this

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then you will see the path being shown there.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a couple of hours until I finally figured out the problem. The main problem in my opinion is that in the [Heroku official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) they use the Old-style middleware that uses `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` which is deprecated, instead of the new `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

> In whitenoise version 4+, the WSGI integration option for Django (which involved editing wsgi.py) has been removed. Instead, you should add WhiteNoise to your middleware list in settings.py and remove any reference to WhiteNoise from wsgi.py. (from [the docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0://))

The following configuration worked like a charm:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # the next line of code is the one that solved my problems
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

]
```

Pay attention to the following Note, also from the docs.

> You might find other third-party middleware that suggests it should be given highest priority at the top of the middleware list. Unless you understand exactly what is happening you should ignore this advice and **always place WhiteNoiseMiddleware above other middleware**.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. The simplest way to find the problem is to use

```
heroku run ls staticfiles/images
```

if images is in the directory where your files should be. This will give you a list of all the files in that directory.

As I found out it was a case issue in the file extension. The file had an extension `.JPG` and I referenced it on the template with an extension `.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

$ pip install whitenoise

add whitenoise in middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

also need to add STATIC_ROOT in setting.py

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

and add media_root in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
        + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and then you can run collectstatic command locally or on server `python manage.py collectstatic`

and it will work properly. you can run this command locally collectstatic and it will work on server.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me

my requirements.txt is

```
whitenoise==6.2.0
static3==0.7.0
webdav4==0.9.7
Django==3.2
# others
```

I delete `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`

and add var `STATICFILES_DIRS`, my `settings.py` :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

if you set  `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, now you should run properly

if you still want use COLLECTSTATIC function
add it manually in `Procfile` file as:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn my_blog.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

my `my_blog.wsgi`file is(it's configed by following a post which cannot be found now):

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_blog.settings')
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```