# Django-cms Whitenoise cannot find static file

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-cms

I have a Django_cms application. It runs correctly both locally and remotely once i deploy. My problem comes when i want to use whitenoise to manage staticfiles. Once i install white noise and adjust my settings.py file with the below details,

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and try to run the server i get the error below.

```
ValueError: The file 'filer/js/addons/popup_handling.js' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f9a96e45690>.
```

This error i get it on my local server and when i run `heroku logs` i get the same error.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Have you solved it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I solved my problem using cling. White noise din't work for me.https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static

Comment: a similar question here. the owner advised me to use cling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641233/django-whitenoise-storage-backend-causes-an-error

Comment: thanks, solved the issue with `whitenoise`. fixed my own issues with configuration.

Comment: @sobolevn how did you fix it? Can you please provide your solution? I am stuck with the problem too.

Comment: I had my `static_root` setting miss-configured. It was pointing to wrong directory. But as I said it was my specific problem.