# Heroku Django app not loading static files (404 Not Found)

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I have been trying to deploy a django app onto heroku. However, it's not able to obtain the static files. I ran `collecstatic` on heroku and there is a `static` folder in the root directory of the app that contains the correct files:
`~/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

cURL:

```
curl 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css' \
-XGET \
-H 'Referer: https://xxx.herokuapp.com/users/login' \
-H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django staticfiles not found on Heroku (with whitenoise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507140/django-staticfiles-not-found-on-heroku-with-whitenoise)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django does not support serving static files in production. However, the fantastic [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) project can integrate into your Django application, and was designed with exactly this purpose in mind.

```
pip install whitenoise
```

add whitenoise to your requirements.txt
add this code in app/wsgi.py

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Answer (score 7):

I've spent some hours before I was able to figure out this. @VipinMohan solution works for whitenoise<4. However, in version 4+, WhiteNoise removes some options which were deprecated in the previous major release. For the record, I am using Django 2.1.

From [the docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise):

> The WhiteNoise middleware should be placed directly after the Django SecurityMiddleware (if you are using it) and before all other middleware.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     # the next line of code is the one that solved my problems
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]
```

Pay attention to the Note in the section of the provided link.

> You might find other third-party middleware that suggests it should be given highest priority at the top of the middleware list. Unless you understand exactly what is happening you should ignore this advice and **always place WhiteNoiseMiddleware above other middleware**.

Answer (score 1):

Add collectstatic to Procfile

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Thanks to this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54063202/11543679)

Answer (score 1):

WhiteNoise configuration should be changed if you use v4.0 or later.
Please refer this [whitenoise-changelog](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0)