# Django Heroku not serving static files when Debug=False

Tags: django, heroku, whitenoise

I'm hosting my **Django** application on **Heroku** and using **whitenoise** to handle serving static files.

Following is content of **settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS += [
    'example.com',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_my_project')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root')
```

But static files are not working.

Setting `Debug=True` is serving static files but not when `Debug=False`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the solution from a [post](https://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku)

Added `collectstatic` to **Procfile**

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

And now every static file is serving including, CSS, js, images and videos.

Answer (score 1):

The Whitenoise middleware should come [after the security middleware and before all other middleware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html). You are currently adding it to the end.

Comment: If you’ve tried that then please update your original question to show the current code. Make sure you have committed and pushed the changes.