# Django Whitenoise with compressed staticfiles

Tags: python, django, django-compressor, whitenoise

I'm not able to get my django project to run with whitenoise and compressed staticfiles (including libsass). In links below, I read that it's only possible by offline compression of needed staticfiles. But when I started up the docker container, running `compress` command

```
docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py compress
```

gives me error:

```
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'sass/app.scss'
```

While trying to request the site gives me following error (as expected?):

```
compressor.exceptions.OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key "..." is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress"
```

Settings are as follows (build with cookiecutter-django, see link for complete code base below):

```
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR("staticfiles"))
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR.path("static"))]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

STATICFILES_FINDERS += ["compressor.finders.CompressorFinder"]

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = [("text/x-scss", "django_libsass.SassCompiler")]
COMPRESS_CACHEABLE_PRECOMPILERS = (("text/x-scss", "django_libsass.SassCompiler"),)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = env.bool("COMPRESS_ENABLED", default=True)
COMPRESS_STORAGE = "compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage"
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
```

So after searching the internet for 1 day; I'm stuck... Thx for any help or suggestion!

Code base: https://github.com/rl-institut/E_Metrobus/tree/compress

which is build with [cookiecutter-django-foundation](https://github.com/Parbhat/cookiecutter-django-foundation)

including the following changes to `config/setttings/production.py`:

```
COMPRESS_STORAGE = "compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage"  # Instead of pre-set "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT  # Just in case
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True  # Needed to run compress offline
```

Possible related links:

- [Whitenoise and django-compressor cause 404 for compressed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105440/)
- [Possible to use WhiteNoise with Django-Compressor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740385/)
- [Django staticfiles not found on Heroku (with whitenoise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507140/)
- https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/486

**EDIT**

Solved it using Justins answer (see below, with additonal changes).
My mistake was trying to compress files with already running container, giving me the error above. After changing Dockerfile with following lines (Notice the duplicate `collectstatic` cmd!):

```
python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python /app/manage.py compress --force
python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

and rebuilding image everything worked like a charm :)
Additionally, diverging from settings above, I had to set `COMPRESS_ENABLED=True` in my settings/env file.

Comment: For me I had 
    `COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' `
from a former heroku installation... changing it to 
    `COMPRESS_STORAGE = "compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`
solved my problem, thanks for the detailed configuration here which hepled me solving my issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

Add this to **project/compose/production/django/start**

```
python /app/manage.py compress --force
```

i.e.

```
python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python /app/manage.py compress --force
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thank you very much.
For me it worked after including a second `python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput` after the compress command. Before, the files have been compressed, but whitenoise didn't see/accept them?! Now, everything works!

Answer (score 0):

this is weird but it work very well.

collect and compress static files by whitenoise

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear
```

set COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'compressor.storage.BrotliCompressorFileStorage'
to make .br files in CACHE directory

```
python manage.py compress --force
```

set COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage'
to make .gzfiles in CACHE directory

```
python manage.py compress --force
```

to add new compressed files to whitenoise: manifest.json, manifest.json.gz,
manifest.json.br
--no-post-process option is to tell whitenoise not to compress static files again.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-post-process
```

make sure to run the commands in order.

to test if whitenoise is working

```
python manage.py runserver --nostatic
```